# How do classes instantiate in Java?

Tags: java, class, new-operator

I came accross the following rule in [JLS8/15.9.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.1):

> The Identifier after the new token must unambiguously denote an inner
>   class that is accessible, non-abstract, not an enum type, and *a member*
>   *of the compile-time type of the Primary expression or the*
>   *ExpressionName*.

I can't imagine what it the last restriction means. Maybe you can give an example of such a member of the compile-time type of the *Primary* expression of the *ExpressionName*?

Comment: The text says _or_, not _of_, in case that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says "If the class instance creation expression is qualified" .. then .. (your quotation)

So, I guess it's this case:

```
package test;

public class Test1 {
    public class Test3{

    }
}
```

And you instantiate it in another class like this:

```
package test;

import test.Test1.Test3;

public class Maker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        Test3 test3 = test1.new Test3();    
    }

}
```

Then,

1. The instance creation expression is qualified:
   `test1.new Test3()` (test1.new, - a qualified new and not an unqualified new)
2. The primary expression is test1
3. The compile-time type of the primary expression is Test1
4. The Identifier after the new token is Test3 and it unambiguously denotes the class Test3
5. Test3 is accessible, non-abstract, not an enum type, and is a member of the compile-time type of Test1, the compile-time type of the primary expression.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I was looking up.